# Apache redirect based on partial URL

Tags: apache, redirect

I would like to run 2 sites on a single apache server but without fixed domains, so basically want anything coming in on any url with the word "site2" in to redirect to the /site2 folder ... e.g.

`http://wordssite2.blah.com   ->   /var/www/html/site2/index.html
    http://wordssite2.blah2.com/index.html  -> /var/www/html/site2/index.html
    http://wordssite2.foo.com/gallery.html -> /var/www/html/site2/gallery.html
    http://wordssite1.blah.com/gallery.html -> /var/www/html/gallery.html`

I'm new to apache, and wouldn't know whether to do this with a redirect rule, or using the VirtualHosts. Redirect seems to support wildcards, VirtualHosts seem to want a fixed domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration should be placed in the vhost file for the domains containing "site2":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2/
        ServerAlias *site2*

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "site2"
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The `ServerAlias` directive is used to tell apache to handle requests which contain the word "site2" and apply this particular vhost configuration.

The `RewriteCond` directive will check whether the domain name of the incoming request contains "site2". The server variable `HTTP_HOST` returns the domain name received in the HTTP request header.

If it is true, the `RewriteRule` will serve the request from "/var/www/html/site2" folder (mentioned in the `DocumentRoot` Directive) and append the URI which is extracted by the `$1` parameter.

Note:

1. You will have to first enable mod_rewrite on Apache for this configuration to work.
2. You should setup correct DNS records for the "site2" domains and direct the traffic to your server.